# Pointers from vectors

Tags: c++, pointers

I have a vector of objects which are pointers but when I print the contents out I get memory addresses, so I was going to copy the vector to a string vector but the methods like copy, assign or swap don't seem to work.

```
std::vector<BmvMessage*> MsgName;
//std::vector<BmvMessage> MsgNameCopy;
//std::string* a;
MsgName = retrieveMessageNameID(Msg).push_onto(MsgName);
std::vector<BmvMessage*>::iterator it;

for (it = MsgName.begin(); it != MsgName.end(); ++it) {
  DCS_LOG_DEBUG("it is not empty");
  MsgName.swap(MsgNameCopy);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if i wrote DCS_LOG_DEBUG("Element" << MsgName[0]) a memory address is displayed

Comment: *"I have a vector of objects which are pointers but when I print the contents out I get memory addresses"* -- Why is there a *but* in that sentence?  A pointer stores a memory address, what would you expect it to print?

Comment: yes that is true i guess i should re-word when i deference it it does not seem to work so do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Why are you using *(raw)* pointers with containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators are like pointers so 'it' is like a pointer to a pointer - deference it and you should be back at your original pointer.

```
it // Is like a pointer to a BmvMessage* or BmvMessage**
*it // Is a BmvMessage*
**it // Is a BmvMessage
```

Comment: ok i shall try DCS_LOG_DEBUG("elements" << **it), that did not seem to work though its only *it that complies but only prints out the memory adrres, is there a way how to copy the elements into a  string vector?

Comment: You have an overload operator<< to print a BmvMessage struct/class right? C++ cannot magically output classes/structs created by the user - you have to write your own output operator

Comment: create you own output operator, do u have any examples of this a websight link maybe?

Comment: Sure thing. This looks pretty complete http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/93-overloading-the-io-operators/

Comment: ohh ok so just have to create the overloaded method and put the DCS_LOG.. print statement inside ok thanks or your help!